# Does moving the US embassy to Jerusalem make a three-state solution more likely?

Tags: israel, foreign-policy, palestine

Back in 2014, the top answer to the following question suggested that a "three-state solution" where Egypt annexes the Gaza Strip and Jordan the West Bank is not viable.

[Does it make sense for Jordan & Egypt to annex Gaza and the West Bank?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4670/does-it-make-sense-for-jordan-egypt-to-annex-gaza-and-the-west-bank)

However, recently, [the Trump administration declared Jerusalem the capital of Israel](http://www.latimes.com/world/middleeast/la-fg-israel-jerusalem-status-20180102-htmlstory.html), and Trump's former Campaign Strategist Stephen Bannon was heard describing the move in the upcoming book "Fire and Fury" (from an [excerpt of the book in New York Magazine](http://nymag.com/daily/intelligencer/2018/01/michael-wolff-fire-and-fury-book-donald-trump.html)):

> Pivoting from Trump himself, Bannon plunged on with the Trump agenda.
>   “Day one we’re moving the U.S. Embassy to Jerusalem. Netanyahu’s
>   all-in. Sheldon” — Adelson, the casino billionaire and far-right
>   Israel defender — “is all-in. We know where we’re heading on this …
>   Let Jordan take the West Bank, let Egypt take Gaza. Let them deal with
>   it. Or sink trying.”
>
> “Where’s Donald on this?” asked Ailes, the clear implication being
>   that Bannon was far out ahead of his benefactor.
>
> “He’s totally onboard.”

Bannon's comments suggest that declaring Jerusalem the capital of Israel/moving the US embassy is part of a larger plan to implement a three-state solution to the Israeli–Palestinian conflict.

How would this work? Why would Jordan and Egypt be more willing to annex the respective territories if Jerusalem is considered the Israeli capital by the US? What is the best interpretation of Bannon's comment "Let them deal with it. Or sink trying"?

Comment: Seems like wishful thinking. Gaza is nothing but trouble for Egypt. Same for the west bank, minus Jerusalem, for Jordan.

Comment: It makes it more likely in Bannon's mind. We can't really tell if it makes it more likely in reality due to lack of meaningful ways to model this probabilistically

Comment: @ugoren true, but don't forget you are basically giving free land to a country. Not to mention the trouble is in large part due to illegal activities at the border. Once this border is removed, the troubles could be easier to deal with. I am sure Egypt and Jordan have plenty of other good reasons to accept this. Including also american aid.

Comment: @user5751924 I am absolutely certain nor Egypt neither Jordan are willing to take several hundreds of thousands of heavily armed highly impoverished refugees. Would you like them on your country?

Comment: @Rekesoft They are not that heavily armed (recall the intifadas ?), and the weapons belong mostly to the palestinian security forces. They are not refugees, the border would move, not them. Their eventual disagreements with Egypt or Jordan could be resolved (Egypt-supported fatah is currently negociated terms of alliance with the hamas). And Jordan is already host to hundreds of thousands of impoverished Syrian refugees that came without free land. All I am saying is it doesn't seem unthinkable that they would say yes.

Comment: @user5751924 Jordan is, as you say, already hosting hundreds of thousands of syrian refugees. It's a kind gesture of their part, and one their people and their government can be proud of. It's not being easy, though, and Jordan will be glad they day they can leave the country back for good.

Comment: A three-state solution to the Palestinian issue where none of the states is one recognized as Palestine? Sounds, literally, dangerous.

Answer (score 5):

The [linked to answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/4672/9459) tells you that the probablity of a three-state
solution (aka
[the Jordanian option](http://www.jpost.com/Jerusalem-Report/Trump-and-the-Jordanian-option-477146)),
in the form that you describe it, was close to zero. Israel doesn't
want to give the West Bank back and Jordan doesn't want to have
it. Egypt taking back the Gaza Strip has been out of the question
since 1979.

The embassy move has been discussed a lot and most analysts have had a
[hard time figuring out](http://nymag.com/daily/intelligencer/2017/12/why-is-trump-intent-on-moving-the-u-s-embassy-to-jerusalem.html)
why it was carried out. But suffice it to say that it
doesn't make a three-state solution *more* likely. The answer to your
question is therefore **no**.

Then why was Stephen Bannon pushing the three-state solution idea?
Possibly because of influence from Sheldon Adelson, the American
casino billionaire and Israel activist. In 2016, he
[donated $25m](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/sep/23/sheldon-adelson-trump-super-pac-donation-25-million)
to the Trump campaign.

Adelson is an opponent to the two-state solution. Among other things,
he has
[claimed](https://www.timesofisrael.com/adelson-palestinians-an-invented-people-out-to-destroy-israel/)
that "the Palestinians are an invented people," that "the purpose of
the existence of Palestinians is to destroy Israel" and that
[a Palestinian state is a](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/24/opinion/sunday/what-sheldon-adelson-wants.html)
"a steppingstone for the destruction of Israel and the Jewish people."
Adelson also bankrolls the
[Heritage Foundation](http://www.heritage.org/) a conservative public
policy think tank that opposes
[Palestinian statehood](http://www.heritage.org/report/the-us-must-oppose-the-palestinian-statehood-effort-the-un)
and favors the
[three-state solution](http://original.antiwar.com/luban/2009/06/04/hawks-push-three-state-solution-for-palestine/).

So if one state is out, due to the "[demographic suicide](https://www.timesofisrael.com/adelson-palestinians-an-invented-people-out-to-destroy-israel/)"
angle, two-states, because Palestinians want to destroy Israel, then the only option left is three states.